# Text classification: Elastic or Apache Spark?

Tags: text-processing, classification

I would like to train a model of text classification to analyze municipal council resolutions of cities.

A resolution usually spoke about: housing, sanitation, local public transportation...
Each resolution will have one or more label to classify it, depending of its thematics.

I need to choose between *Elastic* and *Apache Spark* to do this classification.

---

Having a first look, it seems that:

1. Entering texts into *Elastic* would be simpler and quicker than with *Apache Spark*
2. But putting on each text its label for the training process, maybe not
3. *Apache Spark* looks able to create very deep and precise analysis using multiple algorithms, but they might require some expertise
4. *Elastic* looks being able to give quick responses, but how its responses are justified, by which indicators, and how I can change the behavior of *Elastic* in the case I wouldn't like it, is unknown to me
5. *Elastic* is strong in text analysis regarding to the language used (French for me): I know it won't be tricked by sentences constructions. But what about *Apache Spark* and it's text analysis modules? Are they relying on *solr*, *lucene* too?
6. If I'm using *Elastic* then the plain text will be already parsed, and a search engine already available, if I need later to search some resolutions with "*sanitation*" label and a city name, for example. With *Apache Spark*, I will have to develop a research

But it also seems that *Apache Spark* and *Elastic* cannot be used both at the same time
a way that *Apache Spark* would benefit from *Elastic*, for example.
If I'm wrong and they can, it's a very good news.

Do you have other clues/hints to help me deciding about which one to use?

What others questions should I ask myself before doing a choice?